# Fixed point iteration methods lead to division by zero

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-point-theorems

So I need to prove that for $f(x) = ((x - x^*)^2)h(x)$ assuming $f''(x) \neq 0$ and assuming $f(x)$ be twice continuously differentiable, that Newton's method converges linearly in this case. So $g(x) = x - f(x)/f'(x)$.

I have a rate of convergence theorem that says for the derivatives of $g(x)$ the first derivative that equal zero when $x =$ the fixed point is the order of the convergence so if ($x^*$ is the fixed point) $g'(x*) = 0$ and $g''(x^*) \neq 0$ then the order of convergence is quadratic.

My problem is that in this case $g(x)$ at the fixed point doesn't exist since $f'(x^*)$ = 0 so $g(x^*) = x - 0/0$. I have other questions I need to do that end up like this two with the fixed point method given to me and the $f(x)$ leading to a $0/0$ situation, what do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your presumable don't know the root when you using Newton's method the iteration is performed as 
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$
so technically you never divide by $0$.
However, if  $f'(r)=0$ at the root ($f(r)=0$), it can be proved, that the Newton method will give a linear rate of convergence theorem, instead of regular quadratic rate.

In order to show this one 
have to find the smallest $p$ for which there is a finite number $c\ne0$ such that
$$\frac{\left|x_{n+1}-r\right|}{\left|x_{n}-r\right|^p}=c,$$
where $r$ is the root of $f$, i.e. $f(r)=0$.

$$\frac{\left|x_{n+1}-r\right|}{\left|x_{n}-r\right|^p}=
\frac{\left|x_{n}-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}-r\right|}{\left|x_{n}-r\right|^p}\underset{h=x_n-r}{=}
\left|h^{1-p} \left(1- \frac{f(x_n)}{h f'(x_n)}\right)
\right|
$$
using few terms of Taylor expansion around $r$ (since $x_n=r+h$)of the numerator and denumerator. I think you will also have to assume that $f''(r)\ne0$ or so. The full thing you find [here](http://www.math.utah.edu/~mmedvin/Teaching/Math5610g6860/HandOuts/HO04RootFinding.pdf).

Comment: wait why would |x_n+1 - x_n| = | f(x_n)/f'(x_n)|?

Comment: may be because $$x_{n+1}-x_n=-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$

Comment: sorry, I didnt mean why is there absolute values i mean how do you know x_n+1 - x_n = -f(x_n)/f'(x_n)

Comment: oh wait nvm i get it, you just subtracted xn from both sides

Comment: yes, but I think I suggested you to estimate wrong thing, see the edit in a while

Comment: I'm still a little confused on how the taylor expansion of the numerator and denominator help?

Comment: I've provided a link to a full proof.